# Labelling with loops

Tags: r, loops

Is there a way to transform the labels of all these variables from 0 and 1 to "No" and "Yes" by a loop without making several lines of code.

```
lev_bin<-c(0,1); lab_bin<-c("No","Yes")
Epidem$Cardiac.diag<-factor(Epidem$Cardiac.diag,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Cardiac.morb<-factor(Epidem$Cardiac.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Cong.heart.fail.morb<-factor(Epidem$Cong.heart.fail.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Dementia.morb<-factor(Epidem$Dementia.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Psychic.morb<-factor(Epidem$Psychic.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Chron.pulm.morb<-factor(Epidem$Chron.pulm.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Renal.morb<-factor(Epidem$Renal.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Liver.morb<-factor(Epidem$Liver.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$GI.bleeding.morb<-factor(Epidem$GI.bleeding.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Malignancy.morb<-factor(Epidem$Malignancy.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Immunologic.morb<-factor(Epidem$Immunologic.morb,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Transfer.more.24H<-factor(Epidem$Transfer.more.24H,lev_bin,lab_bin)
Epidem$Def.myocard.infarct<-factor(Epidem$Def.myocard.infarct,lev_bin,lab_bin)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create a vector with variables names that you want to change

```
variables <- c("Cardiac.diag", "Cardiac.morb" ..., "Def.myocard.infarct")
```

you can doit with a subset of `names(Epidem)`

Then you apply a simple loop:

```
for (i in variables){
Epidem[,i] <- factor(epidem[,i], lev_bin, lab_bin) 
}
```